# Реализация перемещения тестового UIView и установка текста метки

Tags: ios, xcode, view, gestures, label

Добрый день. Только начала изучать жесты в iOS, выполняю туториал http://www.appcoda.com/ios-gesture-recognizers/.
Дошла до Pan Gesture Recognizer, и здесь возникла проблема: после присвоения меткам значений вертикальной и горизонтальной скорости, жест "ломается". UIVIew больше не перемещается плавно вместе с курсором мыши, а перепрыгивает в место, где остановился курсор мыши. Значения меток обновляются без проблем.
Ниже приведен код, который реализует перемещение тестового вида:

```
PanViewController.h

@interface PanViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *testView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *horizontalVelocityLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *verticalVelocityLabel;

@end

PanViewController.m

@interface PanViewController ()

- (void)moveViewWithGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer;

@end

@implementation PanViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveViewWithGestureRecognizer:)];
    [self.testView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)moveViewWithGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [panGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

    self.testView.center = touchLocation;
```

После добавления следующих строк в последний метод и возникает проблема с неправильным выполнением жеста перетаскивания, хотя никаких ошибок не возникает:

```
    CGPoint velocity = [panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:self.view];

    self.horizontalVelocityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Horizontal Velocity: %.2f points/sec", velocity.x];
    self.verticalVelocityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertical Velocity: %.2f points/sec", velocity.y];


}
```

Как мне исправить эту "поломку"? Очень хочется понять, что же я неправильно делаю, а не продолжать дальнейшее обучение, не разобравшись до конца с проблемой.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все потому, что при передвижении Вы ставите UIView в центр, а нужно расчитывать и  устанавливать frame:

```
- (void)moveViewWithGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {
    //CGPoint touchLocation = [panGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

    //self.testView.center = touchLocation;


    CGPoint translation = [panGestureRecognizer translationInView:panGestureRecognizer.view];

    CGRect newFrame = self.testView.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = newFrame.origin.y + translation.y;
    newFrame.origin.x = newFrame.origin.x + translation.x;
    self.testView.frame = newFrame;

    [panGestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:panGestureRecognizer.view];

    CGPoint velocity = [panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:self.view];

    self.horizontalVelocityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Horizontal Velocity: %.2f points/sec", velocity.x];
    self.verticalVelocityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vertical Velocity: %.2f points/sec", velocity.y];


}
```

Этот код будет работать только если у Вас будет выключен Autolayout. Если же Autolayout включен, то для этого можно посмотреть вот это обсуждение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129988/ios-dragged-view-is-jumping-back-to-original-position-auto-layout-combined

Вы можете посмотреть реализацию моего кода без autolayout: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2g1Y/EC19pnX2P

Comment: Теперь объект совсем не движется.(( Вот ссылка на мой репозиторий на Гитхабе - https://github.com/NatalyT/GesturesDemo. Возможно, еще нужно уточнить, что тестирую я приложение только на симуляторе, версия Xcode 6.3.2.

Comment: Все потому, что Вы используете autolayout. Об этом есть тема: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129988/ios-dragged-view-is-jumping-back-to-original-position-auto-layout-combined

Comment: @NataliaTatarinteva Вы можете посмотреть реализацию моего кода без autolayout: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2g1Y/EC19pnX2P
Если же Вы хотите использовать вместе с autolayout, то посмотрите ссылку, которую я кинул комментарием выше

Comment: Действительно, выключение autolayout в Main.storyboard фиксит проблему.

Comment: @Anastasia, Ваше решение - самое простое. Достаточно выключить `autolayout` в `Main.storyboard`, без каких-либо изменений кода, и все работает. Ваш комментарий оказался для меня наиболее полезным. Оформите его, как ответ, я приму. Огромное спасибо!))

Comment: @NataliaTatarinteva так выше я и написал, что проблема в том, что Вы используете autolayout. И даже скинул свой проект, с моим кодом, где отключен autolayout. А вот Anastasia это уже и подтвердила

Comment: @NataliaTatarinteva, спасибо, но мой комментарий действительно базируется на комментарии runia (втором сверху), просто я конкретизировала как именно выключить autolayout. Предлагаю runia оформить свой комментарий в еще один ответ :)

Comment: @Anastasia спасибо ;) Добавил концовку в свой ответ под кодом, чтобы на будущее всем было понятно :) 
NataliaTatarinteva можете отметить мой ответ правильным, дабы не плодить кучу ответов. Удачи!

Comment: @runia, даже после изменения Ваш ответ не совсем соответствует действительности. Мне было достаточно просто отключить `autolayout`, без каких-либо изменений кода. Поэтому комментарий @Anastasia и стал для меня наиболее ценным, потому что содержал конкретное указание, что делать. Я же новичок)). @runia, я просто не допоняла Вас, но я тоже безмерно благодарна Вам.))

Comment: @NataliaTatarinteva если использовать Ваш код, то получается такая ситуация: когда вы потяните за угол view, то сначала центр view разместиться там, где палец. В моем же коде если вы тащите за угол, то угол всегда будет находиться там, где палец. Понимаете о чем я?

Comment: @runia, да, Вы правы. Я же говорю: я новичок. Мне еще учиться и учиться!)) Мои знакомые иос-ники не смогли решить эту проблему. Поэтому Вы даже не представляете, как я Вам благодарна за решение проблемы, мучившей меня неделю. Только будьте терпимее к новичкам, не смейтесь над нами! Удачи!

Answer (score 2):

Лучше не используйте `frame` или `center`, используйте для этого `NSLayoutConstaint`

создайте

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstaint *testViewLeft;
```

дальше двигайте ее:

```
self.testViewLeft.constant = newValue;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

чтобы это происходило с анимацией, поместите `layoutIfNeeded()` в блок анимации

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.1 animations: ^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
} completion: nil];
```

сохраните offset точки начала жеста от края view, это поможет сделать движение более плавным вначале

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat panOffset;
```

к тому же в action проверяйте состояние  жеста:

```
- (void)panGestureStateChanged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    switch (sender.state) {
       case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
       self.panOffset = sender.locationInView(contentContainerView).x
       break;
       case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
       CGFloat touchPoint = [sender locationInView:view];
       CGFloat newConstant = touchPoint.x - offset;
       self.testViewLeft.constant = newConstant;
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.03 animations:^{
                        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                    } completion: nil];
       break;
       case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
       panOffset = 0;
       break;
       default: break;
    }
}
```

еще полезным будет стать `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` и реализовать метод, чтобы контроливать когда следует начинать жест, а когда нет:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
if (gestureRecognizer == self.myPanGesture) {
   return (someGestureBeginConditions > 0);
}
return true;
}
```